# Custom Relationship Editor With Service Portal

Tags: servicenow

I am working to create custom Relationship Editor in service portal.
By looking into URL : https://your_domain.service-now.com/$relationshipEditor.do?sysparm_collection=cmdb_ci_network_adapter&sysparm_collectionID=SOME_ID&sysparm_collectionType=cmdb_ci&sysparm_changeset=&sysparm_propose_change=

1. My Question is how can we modify the form as in this case $relationshipEditor.do. How to reach this form for understanding?

Help me with steps to reach the form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately almost all UI Pages that start with a dollar sign `$` are restricted and cannot be looked at.

You may try looking at the old relationship editor for your needs, `ci_relationship_manage`, located under **System UI** > **UI Pages**.

Effectively all this does is load the UI Macro `ci_relationship_manage` located under **System UI** > **UI Macros**.

You might be able to clone that macro and tweak it for your purposes.